# Browser Back button causing the VF page to resubmit again and again

Tags: visualforce

We have a VF page form ( web to lead ) in which after clicking the submit button it goes to another VF page ( having Thank you message). But when we click browser back button the form is getting resubmitted and duplicate records are getting created. We are using standard Lead controller in the VF page. We have set `cache="false"`.

Is there additional thing I have to do as this problem is very new to us. In past there was no such problem.

**Apex**

```
public class RedirectPage { 
    PageReference pr1; 
    PageReference pr2; 
    public PageReference GoToPage(){ 
        try { 
            PageReference cpage = new PageReference('/apex/confirmationPage'); 
            cpage.setRedirect(true);
            pr1 = cpage; 
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } 
        return pr1;
    } 
    public PageReference GetRedir() { 
        try { 
            PageReference telecallerPage = new PageReference('/apex/Proposal_Registration'); 
            telecallerPage.setRedirect(true); 
            pr2 = telecallerPage; 
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } 
        return pr2;
    } 
}
```

**VisualForce**

```
<apex:page controller="RedirectPage" action="{!GoToPage}" />
```

Comment: Can you post some code from the controller? I want to see if you have any actions on the page itself and what is happening inside the constructor.

Comment: Please post some code so we can try to help identify the issue

Comment: Sorry for late reply: Now I have added a blank page in between form submit button and confirmation page( last page). What I want to do is the when user click submit button it will goes to intermediate page and from there it gets automatically directed to last page (in apex:page added action tag to do this). My idea was that whenever a user click browser back button in last page it never goes back to  form page and user always gets redirected to last page. Unfortunately the form is still getting resubmitted even after coming back to last page.... contd..

Comment: code:public class RedirectPage{  
PageReference pr1;  
PageReference pr2;      
public PageReference GoToPage(){  
try{    
    PageReference cpage = new PageReference('/apex/confirmationPage');
    cpage.setRedirect(true);    
    pr1 = cpage;
}catch(Exception e){} 
return pr1;}
    
public PageReference GetRedir() {
try{
    PageReference telecallerPage = new PageReference('/apex/Proposal_Registration');
    telecallerPage.setRedirect(true);
    pr2 = telecallerPage;
}catch(Exception e){} 
return pr2;}
} 
2nd Page: <apex:page controller="RedirectPage" action="{!GoToPage}" >.. contd...

Comment: can anybody guide how to submit the code as the above code is looking very clumsy. Not able to submit in correct format. I also have limit in character.

Comment: Most important point we are not using apex:form . We have written form in JS. Kindly note that. From there we provide retURL that goes to 2nd page (intermediate page, basically a blank page) and then automatically to third page( last page).

Comment: @Rohit were you able to resolve this issue? One important item of note, it is terrible to catch exceptions and then ignore them. Hopefully this code isn't used as-is in a production application.

Comment: Yes Mark. I have solved the problem. Thanks for concern.  Can you please elaborate your last comment. I assure you that I will read it on time.

Answer (score 2):

You can take help from the below code:

```
(function(window, location) {
history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname+"#!/stealingyourhistory");
history.pushState(null, document.title, location.pathname);

window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {
  if(location.hash === "#!/stealingyourhistory") {
        history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname);
        setTimeout(function(){
          location.replace("http://www.xyz.com/");
        },0);
  }
}, false);
}(window, location));
```

this will override your back button and redirect you to the page given in location .replace().
Let me know if this helps.